# My jQuery only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website has a list of games. One feature is being able to "watch" games. It's working well, but I can't reverse an action (watch/unwatch) unless I refresh the page.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('.watch').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var game_id = $(this).data('game_id');
    $('#game-' + game_id + ' .watch').addClass('unwatch').removeClass('watch');

});

$('.unwatch').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var game_id = $(this).data('game_id');
    $('#game-' + game_id + ' .unwatch').addClass('watch').removeClass('unwatch');

});
```

Any ideas? Perhaps I can improve my code as well? Still learning jQuery/Javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you write the line `$('.watch').click(callback);` you attach `callback` to all element having `.watch` class at the moment of that line execution. When you change later the class of an element from .watch to .unwatch, it is not attached to callback you setted for .unwatch elements before.

You need to have a class `.game` for all you games and then  :

```
$('.game').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var game_id = $(this).data('game_id');

    if($('#game-' + game_id).hasClass('unwatch')) {
        $('#game-' + game_id).addClass('watch').removeClass('unwatch');
    } else if ($('#game-' + game_id).hasClass('watch')) {
        $('#game-' + game_id).addClass('unwatch').removeClass('watch');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The event handlers are attached on first page load to the elements matching the selector at that point in time, changing the classes later does not change the event handlers in any way, so you have to think completely different for a toggle functionality

```
$('.watch').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var game_id = $(this).data('game_id');

    if ( $(this).data('flag') ) {
        $('#game-' + game_id + ' .watch').toggleClass('watch unwatch');
    }else{
        $('#game-' + game_id + ' .unwatch').toggleClass('watch unwatch');
    }

    $(this).data('flag', !$(this).data('flag'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide your click event in two different functions

use following jQuery code

```
    //call watch to bind watch click event
    watch();

    // watch method to bind watch class click event
    function watch(){
      $('.watch').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var game_id = $(this).data('game_id');
        $('#game-' + game_id ).addClass('unwatch').removeClass('watch');

        //bind unwatch class click event
        unwatch();
      });
    }

// unwatch method to bind unwatch class click event
    function unwatch(){
      $('.unwatch').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var game_id = $(this).data('game_id');
        $('#game-' + game_id ).addClass('watch').removeClass('unwatch');

        //bind watch class click event
        watch();
      });
    }
```